# Why does the Python-Instagram API return different images based on a different radius?

Tags: python, instagram

I'm using the [Python-Instagram](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/) API and am confused why I get completely different results between:

`places = api.media_search(lat=36.117590,lng=-115.171589, distance=50)`

and

`places = api.media_search(lat=36.117590,lng=-115.171589, distance=500)`

One would think that increasing the radius to 500 meters would include the pics from 50 meters as well, as 50 is a subset of 500, but the results for 500 meters are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that its because the 50m results *are* a subset of the 500m results; however, Instagram doesn't return all images upon a single call, so you probably just don't see any of the 50m results on your first response.

Check the [API documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) section about pagination.  In particular:

> On views where pagination is present, we also support the "count" parameter. Simply set this to the number of items you'd like to receive.

There's a default count initially, if I recall correctly its around 25.

Comment: Good tip. Unfortunately, I'm only getting 3 images with 50m and 4 (completely different) images with 500m, so it doesn't come down to needing pagination.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong, but the search with a distance of 500m is now including the 50m results if I add count=50 as a parameter. Thank you.

Comment: Bizarre -- sometimes APIs are weird.  But glad to hear it works now!